# l'Hopital's Rule and Differentiable Functions

Tags: real-analysis

My least favorite topic concerning Real Analysis this term was dealing with manipulating the definition of derivative to suit certain situation - I don't quite understand how or when to do it, and it's got me caught on this problem. Here goes:

f and g are both defined on an A and are differentiable at a in A.

a) Find $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{af(x) - xf(a)}{x-a}$

Alright, so concerning rearranging here, I feel like I should be able to add something to the numerator to help condense the function, but I'm not sure what.

b) Find $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{h(a)g(x) - h(x)g(a)}{x-a}$

Same thing as above, only I'm a little confused as to whether the use of functions is different from elements in the outcome of the limit.

c) Explain why l'Hopital's rule doesn't work for parts a) and b)

Finally, based on previous experience, I'm kind of assuming I wasn't able to use the rule because f and g need to be differentiable near a - best guess.

I apologize for the lack of proper formatting, I'm still getting used to the site.

Please help, and thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For the first write it like that $\frac {af(x) -xf(x)+xf(x)-xf(a)}{x-a}=\frac {-f(x)(x-a)+x(f(x)-f(a))}{x-a}=-f(x)+x\frac {f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ and thus $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{af(x) - xf(a)}{x-a}=-f(a)+af'(a)$.

Same work for the second

and you cannot use L'Hospital's argument because you only know that $f$ is differentiable at $a$. If it was everywhere then you could use it

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate it - I forgot that you could do that with xf(x) in the middle of the equation

Answer (score 0):

(a) $$\begin{align}
 \lim_{x\to a} \frac{af(x)-xf(a)}{x-a}&=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{af(x)+xf(x)-xf(x)-xf(a)}{x-a} \\
&=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{(a-x)f(x)+x(f(x)-f(a))}{x-a} \\
&=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{x(f(x)-f(a))}{x-a}-f(x) \\
&=af'(a)-f(a)
\end{align}$$

That should give you an idea of how to approach the other ones.